# how create a comment on commit with github actions?

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

i use github action with this config

```
name: Node CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: install node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12.x
      - name: npm install
        run: npm install
      - name: npm build
        run: npm run build --if-present
      - name: npm test
        run: npm test
      - name: make storybook
        run: npm run build-storybook
      - uses: dswistowski/surge-sh-action@v1
        with:
          domain: 'https://react-strix-$(git rev-parse --short HEAD).surge.sh'
          project: '.out'
          login: straxico@gmail.com
          token: ${{ secrets.SURGE_PASSWORD }}
      - name: deploy image
        run: |
          docker login docker.pkg.github.com --username straxico --password ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
          docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag docker.pkg.github.com/straxico/react-strix/master:$(git describe --tags)
          docker push docker.pkg.github.com/straxico/react-strix/master:$(git describe --tags)
```

I want to automatically create a comment on the latest pushed commit wite msg include my storybook and docker URL. like "now" bot

[image]

**How can write a comment on commit with github actions?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update:** I wrote an action to simplify creating commit comments. I will leave the original solution below for reference.

See [commit-comment](https://github.com/peter-evans/commit-comment) for full usage details.

```
      - name: Create commit comment
        uses: peter-evans/commit-comment@v1
        with:
          body: |
            This is a multi-line test comment
            - With GitHub **Markdown**
            - Created by [commit-comment][1]

            [1]: https://github.com/peter-evans/commit-comment
```

[image: commit-comment action example]

**Original Solution:** The following workflow should be a good starting point. You can find the full documentation for the API here:
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/comments/#create-a-commit-comment

```
name: commit comment
on: push
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Add commit comment
        run: |
          jq -nc '{"body": "test comment"}' | \
          curl -sL  -X POST -d @- \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
            -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
            "https://api.github.com/repos/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/commits/$GITHUB_SHA/comments"
```

It will create a comment on the commit like this.
[image: commit comment example]

Comment: Is it possible to embed markdown generated by CI (for example from running create_markdown.py) and post the generated markdown to the comment? Maybe read the generated markdown as the body?